# Grepl Over Every Column in Dataframe

Tags: r, string

I have this dataframe in R:

```
col1 = c("abc", "cbe", "ddd")
col2 = c("hbc", "lbc","uhr")
id = c(1,2,3)

example = data.frame(id, col1, col2)
```

I want to select all rows that contain "bc" in any column. This would look like this:

```
 id col1 col2
1  1  abc  hbc
2  2  cbe  lbc
```

I know how to do this for a single column:

```
# almost works
select_col_1 = example[grepl("bc", example$col1, ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

- But is there a way to repeat this for every column in the data frame?

I tried to do this with the "lapply" statement:

```
lapply(example, function(x){x[grepl('bc', example, ignore.case = TRUE)])
```

But I don't think I am doing this correctly.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: `example[rowSums(sapply(example[-1], grepl, pattern = "bc")) > 0, ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `dplyr` package which supplies `filter()` to select rows, `everything()` to select all columns and `if_any()` for a result in any column.

```
library(dplyr)
example %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl("bc", .)))
```

Result:

```
  id col1 col2
1  1  abc  hbc
2  2  cbe  lbc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `lapply`, you can use the following code:

```r
col1 = c("abc", "cbe", "ddd")
col2 = c("hbc", "lbc","uhr")
id = c(1,2,3)

example = data.frame(id, col1, col2)

example[Reduce(`|`, lapply(example[-1], grepl, pattern="bc")),]
#>   id col1 col2
#> 1  1  abc  hbc
#> 2  2  cbe  lbc
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @ Quinten: Thank you so much! Why is the "Reduce" and `|` necessary in this code? thank you!